# How can I calculate the distance between the sides of a rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

In this example:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label10.Text = ((n - 1) * 4).ToString();
    _mrect = new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, point.X), Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, point.Y),
                                Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - point.X), Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - point.Y));
}
```

**_mrect is:**

```
X = 125
Y = 144
Width = 250 
Height = 169
```

I want to find the distance between the left edge of the rectangle to the right edge. And the distance between the top edge to the bottom edge.

Comment: How are those distances different from the width and height you have given us?

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but surely "distance between the left edge of the rectangle to the right edge" = width and "distance between the top edge to the bottom edge" = height.

Comment: Change *point.X*, *point.Y* to *e.X* and *e.Y*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please note that!

[image]

then, your answer is `Width` and `Height`,

for more information: http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/winprog/pointsizerect.htm